# Description of families of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ using boolean valued functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

```
Let P(R) denote the power set of R; that is, the set of all subsets of R. 
We’re going to define the function T : P(R) → {0, 1} and the function A P(R) → {0, 1} 
as follows:

T(S) = 1 if and only if ∃b ∈ R, ∀x ∈ S, x > b
A(S) = 1 if and only if ∃b ∈ S, ∀x ∈ S, x ≤ b.

(a) Let S1 = N, S2 = (−∞, 0], and S3 = R. Fill in the table:

   S1 S2 S3
T
A

(b) Is there any set S ⊆ R such that T(S) = 1 = A(S)? If so, give an example 
of such a set and explain why it satisfies the condition.
```

I'm completely stuck and I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: Do you know about *power-set* $\mathcal P(A)$ of a set $A$ ?

Comment: Here is how to start : Can you explain with words for example what is the property of $S$ when $T(S)=1$ ?

Comment: The function $T$ assigns to every element of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, i.e. to every *subset* of $\mathbb R$ a value: either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: The function $T$ assigns to a subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ the value $1$ if there is a *real* number $b$ that is *less than* every number in $s$.

Comment: Consider now the subset $S_1= \mathbb N$; we have that $\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,2,\ldots \}$ and clearly $- \dfrac 1 2$ is less than every number in $S_1$. Thus, the defining condition for $T$ says that: $T(S_1)=1$.

Comment: And so on......